# Running an asynchronous function in js beforeunload event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension and I want to prompt the user before they leave the page. I can do it in the `beforeunload` event; but I need to check a variable in local storage to decide whether to show the prompt or not. But since `chrome.storage.local.get` is async, the code will continue the execution before I can check that variable. This is my code:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    chrome.storage.local.get('state',function(val){
        if(val.state==='syncing'){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = '';    
        }
    })
});
```

Is there a way to make that `chrome.storage.local.get` function act synchronously? Or are there any other solutions?

Comment: You can't make `chrome.storage` synchronous. You'll have to use a different storage e.g. `window.localStorage`

Comment: @wOxxOm i have chrome extension issue. Kindly tell me what i am doing wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63285684/issue-in-website-login-using-chrome-extension